# CRUD generator yii2 error

Tags: php, yii2

I have error `"syntax error, unexpected '}'"` in yii2 CRUD generator. I created controller CountryController in basic/controllers path, model Country in basic/models path and folder country in views. I'm trying to make CRUD operation with parameters:

Model Class : app\models\Country

Search Model Class : app\models\CountrySearch

Controller Class : app\controllers\CountryController

View path : @app/views/country

and have error. I cant find solution in google and dont know what to do.
**ERROR:**

```
 in W:\XAMPP\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\crud\default\views\_search.php at line 28
19202122232425262728293031323334353637 
<div class="<?= Inflector::camel2id(StringHelper::basename($generator->modelClass)) ?>-search">

    <?= "<?php " ?>$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['index'],
        'method' => 'get',
    <?php if ($generator->enablePjax) 
        ?>'options' => [
            'data-pjax'   => 1
        ],<?php } >
    ]); ?>

<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($generator->getColumnNames() as $attribute) {
    if (++$count < 6) {
        echo "    <?= " . $generator->generateActiveSearchField($attribute) . " ?>\n\n";
    } else {
        echo "    <?php // echo " . $generator->generateActiveSearchField($attribute) . " ?>\n\n";
2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
$_GET = [
    'r' => 'gii/default/view',
    'id' => 'crud',
];

$_POST = [
    '_csrf' => 'ZFFUX0VCUjgAMhwAKDgwZ1UQFw8dexZPLwtlZhEMF2AJAh0ZEi8QFQ==',
    'Generator' => [
        'modelClass' => 'app\\models\\Country',
        'searchModelClass' => 'app\\models\\CountrySearch',
        'controllerClass' => 'app\\controllers\\CountryController',
        'viewPath' => '@app/views/country',
        'baseControllerClass' => 'yii\\web\\Controller',
        'indexWidgetType' => 'grid',
        'enableI18N' => '0',
        'enablePjax' => '0',
        'messageCategory' => 'app',
        'template' => 'default',
    ],
    'preview' => '',
];

$_COOKIE = [
    'Phpstorm-b0412478' => '63e8918e-ac29-43de-9816-571b71512aad',
    '_csrf' => 'e3a51f05887c990dee11a82408437a3e87c4de7d372dba216a0834374d5b602ca:2:{i:0;s:5:"_csrf";i:1;s:32:"dcH_mzb_1ACPX9DwKZ19TNEXmSIFWmB-";}',
    'PHPSESSID' => '2a91078gc1nh6q5br71p0hkuu6',
    '_identity' => '8142bf058f7de9bda458b829902ac7db3b69c135c0c908aaaefe8bf2105e8d62a:2:{i:0;s:9:"_identity";i:1;s:28:"["100","test100key",2592000]";}',
];
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close if condition ,where it is open,try below one

```
<?= "<?php " ?>$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
<?php if ($generator->enablePjax) {
    ?>'options' => [
        'data-pjax'   => 1
    ],<?php } >
]); ?>
```

Comment: it work,thank you! Problem was in file:
 basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\crud\default\views\_search.php